# How to correctly share data between Fragements over ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, viewmodel

In my app I use Navigation Component and also, use `ViewModel` to share data between Fragments. This is my scenario, Fragment `A`, Fragment `B`, and Fragment `C`. `A` shares string data with `B` and `B` shares it with `C`, where as in `C` the user edit the shared string and goes back to `B` with edited string data. I share data over a `ViewModel` class like this:

```
class Share : ViewModel() {
    val shared = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun share(share: String?) {
        shared.value = share!!
    }
}
```

From `A` I send the string to `B` like this

```
...

private val share: Share by activityViewModels()

...

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        ...
        // Let's say, this is executed in some onClickListener {}
        share.share("My String for B!")
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_a_to_nav_b)
        ...
}
...
```

According to [Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), to receive shared string in `B`, I have to observe data like this:

```
...
private var sharedString = ""
private val share: Share by activityViewModels()
    
...
    
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...
    share.shared.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { // shared String })
    ...
}
```

First problem:

I cannot access the `observe` to get the string like this:

```
...
var sharedString = ""
share.shared.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { 
    sharedString = it // The value is not assigned!
})
println(sharedString) // This prints nothing!
...
```

Therefore, I have to call a method to be able to access it:

```
share.shared.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { get(it) })

...

private fun get(string: String) {
    println(string) // This prints the shared string "My String for B!"!
}
```

The next problem is that, according to that approach, sometimes app crashes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myapp.BFragment.get (BFragment.java:45) // -> this is the line of share.shared.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { get(it) })
  at com.myapp.BFragment.onViewCreated$lambda-3 (BFragment.java:25) // -> this is the line of  private val share: Share by activityViewModels()
  at com.myapp.BFragment$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$e6af021286f0d4217981b099cd8f3b0ac57de6c0ebe35bee4010f87e07a6ecac$2.onChanged (BFragment.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java:133)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue (LiveData.java:146)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged (LiveData.java:468)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged (LiveData.java:425)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass (LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync (LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState (LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent (FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:88)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:3028)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start (FragmentStateManager.java:589)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:300)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2189)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2106)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2002)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run (FragmentManager.java:524)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8587)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

The next thing, I share that string to `C` and edit there:

```
...
// Let's say again, this is executed in some onClickListener {}
share.share(sharedString)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_b_to_nav_c)
...
```

And in `C` I get it like this:

```
private val share: Share by activityViewModels()

...
    
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...
    val string = share.shared.value!! // As you can see without calling observe.

    // Now we change the value and send it back
    share.share("My new string for B!")
    findNavController().navigateUp()
    ...
}
```

Questions:

1. What is the best approach in this case, to observe the shared data like in `B` or get directly  over value like in `C`?
2. Why does the app sometimes crash?
3. Do I do it in wrong way or miss something?

I do not think that the Google's approach is the best solution. I think they had to bring something different and better solution to allow data sharing between fragments before releasing the navigation component. That does not look effective to me.

Nevertheless, I am trying to get it done working without exceptions.

I searched for a solution and also, tried to find the problem with that exception, but no success yet.

Comment: side note, but you have a class called `Share` with a function called `share` which takes a value of `share: String?` which then sets `shared.value = share!!`. hope all of this makes sense to you, from the outside i wouldn't be happy with your naming :) also, why take a nullable if you're just going to throw an exception with `shared.value = share!!`

Comment: also, why do you need MutableLiveData ? do you really want to observe the value or do you just need a string ? i can't really see a use for MutableLiveData

Comment: `I do not think that the Google's approach is the best solution.` well, you're not really using it correctly and not using everything they are giving you :) you can pass data with the navigation component _without_ having to use a view model at all, [Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)

Comment: did you used dagger?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for reply. Yes, the naming is not perfect. I have to rename that corrected. Honestly, I am not sure whether I need MutableLiveData or note, I just followed the Google's example. However, I think it makes since, since the B observes the data coming from A and C. As a result, I am new to Android and of course, I could do it wrong or even understood wrong, whatever. Nevertheless, trying to get the right implementation way. :)

Comment: from A to B i don't see a use for MutableLiveData, it could just use a string, from B to C and then back to B, you potentially might not need it either, you can test by just removing MutableLiveData and just using a String

Comment: So, I removed MutableLiveData and used there only one String variable. That did not make sense. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jetpack navigation component, you can try passing objects/strings via nav args (navigation arguments).
Personally, I feel it to be lot more easier when passing data between fragments.
Article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigating-with-safeargs-bf26c17b1269

You need to add arguments to destination fragment with data type and default value.
So when you navigation, you can add the argument and fetch the value from destination fragment like this,

```
private val dataFromArgument
        by lazy { DestinationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).variableYouPassed}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried to use this way. However, I read somewhere, that the shared data in this way is not shared only within the app, but it can also be fetched by from another apps on device. Not sure, if this is treue. But nevertheless, I removed the `MutableLiveData` from the `ViewModel` class (thanks to @a_local_nobody) and now it works stable, at least no issue so far. Anyway, thank you so much for your response. Tha helps me to get into topic more deeply and to extend my experience and understanding.